# Linking two fields from one transaction table to another master table field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, inner-join, master-detail

I have the following tables in crystal report. These tables handle movement of items from one location to another.


**TM_LOCMOV** -- Transaction Header table
**TD_LOCMOV** -- Transaction Detail table 
**M_LOCATION** -- Location Master table

In TD_LOCMOV, two fields for from location and to location
**TD_LOCMOV_FromLocSlNo**
**TD_LOCMOV_ToLocSlNo**

TD_LOCMOV inner join with M_LOCATION


I need to create a report showing TransNo,item,from location and to location.

The problem is if I link TD_LOCMOV_FromLocSlNo and TD_LOCMOV_ToLocSlNo with M_LOCATION_SlNo, the report shows from and to location as same.

How to link TD_LOCMOV with M_LOCATION

In crystal report how to link(inner join) two fields from same table to a master(location) table.

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you could share the SQL Query your report is using.  This would allow us to see exactly how your tables are joined and which columns they are using. I suspect you need to add the M_LOCATION table to your report's database twice using an alias for each, so you can join it with bot hthe From and To location values on your Transaction table, but I would be more confident in this if I could see your query first.

Comment: Depends on what fields you are linking from TD tables to M tables.. In the sense if you link location names then there is high possiblity you get both to and from locations, Also from the data you provided it is difficult to understand how are you picking the data, Because you didn't mention for what detail you are calculating To and From locations

Comment: As you mentioned added alias tables for location as M_LOCATION_TO and linked M_LOCATION_SlNo with TD_LOCMOV  table TD_LOCMOV_ToLocSlNo field. It is working now. Thanks for the support.